# How to append vertically 2 images with imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to make vertical my multiple images as expected with following code.

```
convert 1.jpg 2.jpg -gravity North -append out.jpg
```

But I want 2.png as first file and 1.png as second. I know I can make it with `convert 2.jpg 1.jpg -gravity North -append out.jpg` command but actually I want to create them wiht `convert 1.jpg 2.jpg -gravity North -append out.jpg` command.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The images are read into a list. Use [-clone](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#clone) to copy an image at index to the end of the image list, and [-delete](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#delete) to remove an image at index.

So to swap `1.jpg` with `2.jpg` the following would work.

```
 convert 1.jpg 2.jpg -clone 0 -delete 0 -gravity North -append out.jpg
```

A visual breakdown...

```
# Image list
[ "1.jpg", "2.jpg" ]

# After -clone 0
[ "1.jpg", "2.jpg", "1.jpg" ]

# After -delete 0
[ "2.jpg", "1.jpg"]
```

### EDIT

From a note in the [Usage Layers](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/) article.

> As only two images were involved we could have just used "+swap" or "-reverse" instead of [...].

So you can simplify the above with one of the two options.

```
convert 1.jpg 2.jpg +swap -gravity North -append out.jpg
convert 1.jpg 2.jpg -reverse -gravity North -append out.jpg
```